# Change JScrollBar Thumb Size?

Tags: java, swing, slider, jscrollbar

I have a JScrollBar on my frame, not in a ScrollFrame, and the scrollbar knob/slider is really thin. I tried changing the properties of the scrollbar, and I tried making a custom JScrollBar component, but I wasn't able to find a way to change the size of the Scrollbar's knob. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: please did you read offcial Oracle tutorial how to use scrollpanes

Comment: When you say `"and the scrollbar knob/slider is really thin"`, is this for a horizontal scrollbar or a vertical one?  The reason I ask is that when I hear "thin", I equate that to left-to-right width. So, a wide horizontal scroll thumb indicates that not much scrolling is available, whereas a thin horizontal thumb indicates that there is a lot of scrolling available. This IMHO should not be changed, since it gives the user a visual indication to the amount of scrolling available. If you were referring to the width of a vertical scroll slider/thumb, then that's another story.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I mean is I have a scrollbar like this:
`([<]--[]------------[>])`
But I want a scrollbar like this:
`([<]--[       ]-----[>])`

Comment: @BenWoodworth Then I'd suggest not changing it. A small thumb is a visual indicator of how much can be scrolled (a lot), whereas a thicker thumb indicates that there isn't much to scroll. More content = smaller thumb. Changing the thickness would not only visually fool the user, but would also require you to manage the scrolling. Is this a requirement, or just an experiment of your own?

Answer (score 2):

A little late but still some people might need that too.
I also had this issue few days ago so i checked `JScrollBar` class and `BasicScrollBarUI`.

To have a fixed size for thumb all you have to do is to add this line before using/declaring any `JScrollBar`:

```
UIManager.put( "ScrollBar.minimumThumbSize", new Dimension( wanted_width, wanted_height ) );
```

to force thumb never go below wanted size.

`ScrollBar.maximumThumbSize` is `UIManager` property key

Answer (score 1):

Correct use of `setVisibleAmount` would solve the purpose.

As we all know, size of the thumb indicates the visible amount of the underlying content. e.g. for horizontal scroll-bar if 50% of the content is visible, thumb width is 50% of it's track width.

In case of `JScrollBar`, default value of the `visibleAmount` is set to 10. Size of thumb is proportional to the ratio `visibleAmount / (maximum - minimum)`.

This would spoil the default experience, though.

I hope this answers the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks @Alexis for the comment. Have added some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Let the [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and the [look & feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) do the work. This example shows a `NimbusLookAndFeel` scrollbar in the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` area of the frame's content pane. Note how `pack()` causes the bar to adopt the width of the center panel and the preferred height defined by the L&F.

Addendum: The actual painting of the scrollbar's thumb is handled by the `ScrollBarUI` implementation of `paintThumb()` for a given [Look & Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html). You can substitute your own or use a [third party variation](http://www.jwrapper.com/1/post/2013/09/6-great-look-and-feels-to-make-your-java-app-pretty.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22766340/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(240, 120);
            }
        });
        f.add(new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```